# Dapper dynamic query for resource filtering

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, dapper

I am trying to do resource filtering the same way I would be using queryable in EF Core but this time with Dapper. In my case, I wish to get all reports and want to be able to query based on the passed filter parameters. This is so far what I have:

```
        public async Task<List<IssueReport>> GetAll(int? userId = null, bool? onlyOpenIssues = null, int? issueType = null)
    {
        await using var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
        var baseQuery = "SELECT * FROM IssueReports";

        //TODO: Add resource filtering logic here

        var result = await connection.QueryAsync<IssueReport>(baseQuery);

        return result.ToList();
    }
```

What can I do in Dapper to dynamically handle filtering for all those passed parameters as well as handling the case of them being null and not querying them in those cases?

Comment: You can use the WHERE in sql query and send those info as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

> What can I do in Dapper to dynamically handle filtering for all those passed parameters as well as handling the case of them being null and not querying them in those cases?

You can check my demo:

Almost the same in efcore, use sql command to execute the query,open database and fill

the result to a list, then close database and return the result.

In this example, when I pass userId=1 to this action, it will search the table where Id=1:

```
public async Task<List<IssueReport>> GetAll(int? userId = null)
    {
        var result =new List<IssueReport>();
        var baseQuery = @"SELECT * FROM IssueReport WHERE Id = @Id";
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("***your connection string**"))
        {
            connection.Open();
            result = (List<IssueReport>)connection.Query<IssueReport>(baseQuery,new { Id = userId }); //@Id is defined like this
            connection.Close();
        }
        return result.ToList();
    }
```

Result:

[image]